# APC Smart UPS, Synology DS918+ and Mac mini

Tags: mac, ups, synology-diskstation

I have a new APC Smart-UPS C 1000, a 2018 Mac mini, and a Synology DS918+. I am trying to figure out if there is a way that when the battery gets low, the Mac and the Synology can both safely shut down.

The Synology supports SNMP, and although some of the literature for this UPS mentions SNMP support, I can't figure out how to make that happen. So, as it stands right now, I can connect *either* the Mac or the Synology to the UPS via USB, and it will work. But I can't figure out how to make the Synology signal a shutdown to the Mac or vice-versa or how to make it all work over the network. The

Comment: Not making this an answer because I don't know definitively, but my UPS has a USB connection that sends a signal to the computer it's attached to that it's running on battery power. I have it configured to send a shutdown signal if the power is off for more than ~10 minutes. I'd bet yours has a similar feature on the included CD, at least for the Mac. I would be doubtful about the Synology unless it's built into the Synology software

Comment: The UPS and the Synology can definitely talk via USB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain how it works with a NAS. But for computers, you can put an APC agent on each computer and make sure the UPS has a network card (USB will not work for this).

Here is an APC Forum Article to help inform you

https://forums.apc.com/spaces/5/smart-ups-symmetra-lx-rm/forums/general/5391/how-to-have-single-ups-shutdown-multiple-servers

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.